# styling is not applying in mobile screen

Tags: css, reactjs, mobile, error-handling, inline-styles

I wrote inline styling on img tag. But it is not working in a mobile browser.

```
<img 
 ref={...} 
 loading="lazy" 
 className="rounded mx-auto d-block"
 src={...}
 alt="..."
 style={{
 width: '100px',
 padding: '20px',
 objectFit: 'contain',
 }}></img>
```

for debugging when I open the developer tool, I couldn't find my styling there. which is not for only this image all images have the same problem. where I am using inline styling.

```
<img loading="lazy" class="rounded mx-auto d-block" src="..." alt="...">
```

this is what looks like, styling disappeared from img tag.

Also, I am getting this error in the production project only, in development is it working fine.

What I have tried

- update `<meta tag>`
- I am not using any media query I make sure
- it's inline styling so it should have more important than another styling like external CSS files.
- I clear my cache and try to run in incognito but same error.

Answer (score 0):

It is a very simple mistake. Your inline css style syntax is just invalid  `style={{ width: '100px', padding: '20px', objectFit: 'contain', }}`. You can't use curly braces in style property. It's just colons and quotes. The right syntax is `style="width: 100px; padding: 20px; object-fit: contain"`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am using react so in react inline styling should be inside Curly braces. thank you so much for your reply. Sorry about not mentioning that.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for replying. Have you figured it out?